# loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched

Tags: linux, perl

Can not run Pac-manager after installing deb file,

Downloaded Pac Manger from : https://sourceforge.net/projects/pacmanager/

When run

> pac

in the terminal , showing below problem

> xs/Vte.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got
>   handshake key 0xdb00080, needed 0xdb80080)

System:

> Linux PC-pc 4.4.0-3-deepin-amd64 #1 SMP Deepin 4.4.30-2 (2016-12-01)
>   x86_64 GNU/Linux

Thanks.

Comment: Checked this link already?
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=213408

Comment: Also seems like someone else also had this problem and reported it as a bug : https://github.com/perseo22/pacmanager/issues/15

Comment: I've managed in my Arch with several additional components, stuck with deepin , thank you for your support.

Comment: I am stuck with ubuntu 18.04, no way to work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The work on the PAC manager project has been discontinued [[*]](https://github.com/perseo22/pacmanager/issues/57), you may want to give a try to [Ásbrú Connection Manager](https://www.asbru-cm.net/). It's a fork for  which you can find a Debian based package for Gnome2::Vte.